# opencv:: remap() function

Tags: opencv, remap

```
cv::remap(imageA,
          dst1,
          map_x,
          map_y,
          cv::INTER_LINEAR,
          cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,
          cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
```

can any body explain `cv::INTER_LINEAR` and `cv::BORDER_CONSTANT` for me? Except this, what does other option like `BORDER_TRANSPARENT` mean? Please list all the options and explanations. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`remap()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap) will apply a generic geometrical transformation to an image.

> **can any body explain cv::INTER_LINEAR and cv::BORDER_CONSTANT for me?**

`cv::INTER_LINEAR` is the parameter for setting interpolation method, i.e. to use the bilinear interpolation. Besides this, there are other methods you can use:

- `INTER_NEAREST` - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
- `INTER_CUBIC` - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
- `INTER_LANCZOS4` - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood

`cv::BORDER_CONSTANT` is the parameter for setting pixel extrapolation method. When `borderMode=BORDER_TRANSPARENT`, it means that the pixels in the destination image that corresponds to the “outliers” in the source image are not modified by the function.

---

**P.S.:** for such questions, you can easily find useful info from [OpenCV's online documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/).